# Is this result of the derivative of the composition of two functions correct?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

I have the following functions:

$f(x,y)=xy,\; g(t)=(e^t,\cos(t))$

And I want to calculate the derivative matrix of $f$ after $g.$

I calculate the jacobian matrix of $f$, which was a matrix, like

$$
    D_f=\begin{bmatrix}
    y & x
    \end{bmatrix}
$$

then on the components of $g$

$$
    D_f(e^t,\cos(t))=\begin{bmatrix}
    \cos(t) & e^t
    \end{bmatrix}
$$

then calculate the matrix of $g$

$$
    D_g(e^t,\cos(t))=\begin{bmatrix}
    e^t \\ 
    -\sin(t)
    \end{bmatrix}
$$

then to calculate the matrix of the derivatives of $f$ after $g$, I multiplied the matrices

$$
    D_f(e^t,\cos(t))=\begin{bmatrix}
    \cos(t) & e^t
    \end{bmatrix}
$$

times

$$
    D_g(e^t,\cos(t))=\begin{bmatrix}
    e^t \\ 
    -\sin(t)
    \end{bmatrix}$$

$= \cos(t)e^t-e^t\sin(t).$

I have no way of checking if this is correct. Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is correct. You can easily check this yourself. The composition is given by
\begin{align}
f(g(t))=f(e^{t},\cos (t))=e^{t}\cos(t).
\end{align}
If we differentiate this function we get
\begin{align}
(f(g(t))'=\frac{d}{dt}(e^t\cos(t))=e^t\cos (t)-e^t\sin(t)
\end{align}